# AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'split' (options list using pick library)

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

## ***-BEGINNER TO PYTHON***

**(Using pick library, Python 3.11 & trying to make a quizzing game/app?)**

*I'm trying to get a list of answers from a file that looks like this, but can be altered for different questions and number of possible answers:*

```
3
Question 1
2
Answer 1 (1)
Answer 2 (1)
Answer 2 (1)
Question 2
4
Answer 1 (2)
Answer 2 (2)
Answer 3 (2)
Answer 4 (2)
Answer 3 (2)
Question 3
2
Answer 1 (3)
Answer 2 (3)
Answer 2 (3)
```

*The first line of the file is the number of total questions in the file.
The second line of the file is the title of the first question.
The third line of the file is the number of total possible answers in the file.
The next lines are the possible answers for the question.
Which are then followed by the correct answer to the question.*

## **ERROR:**

The error message I'm getting is:

```
'tuple' object has no attribute 'split'
  File "C:\Users\username\Desktop\Applications\Quizzable\Quizzable.py", line 166, in <module>
    option, index = pick(options, title, indicator='[>]', default_index=0)
                    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'split'
```

I know that it's something wrong with the 'options' list variable, but I don't know how to fix it.
The variable is correctly listing
`['Answer 1 (1)', 'Answer 2 (1)']`
as expected. But the pick library isn't handling it correctly.

On other occasions such as this

```
quizzes = os.listdir()
title = '-----------\n QUIZZABLE \n-----------\n   Quiz    \n-----------'
options = [quizzes, 'Return']
option, index = pick(options, title, indicator='[>]', default_index=0)
```

it is being interpreted the way it should, so: what am I doing wrong?

```
with open(str(option)[2:-2], 'r') as quiz:
    quiz_info = [line.strip() for line in quiz]
    quiz_title = str(option)
    title = '-----------\n QUIZZABLE \n-----------\n   Quiz    \n-----------\n\nQuiz:', quiz_title
    quiz_question_total = quiz_info[0]
    quiz_score = 0
    quiz_question_count = int(1)
    quiz_current_line = int(1)
    while quiz_question_count <= int(quiz_question_total):
        quiz_question = quiz_info[int(quiz_current_line)]
        quiz_current_line = int(quiz_current_line) + int(1)
        quiz_question_option_count = quiz_info[int(quiz_current_line)]
        quiz_current_line = int(quiz_current_line) + int(1)
        quiz_question_option = int(1)
        options = []
        while quiz_question_option <= int(quiz_question_option_count):
            options += [quiz_info[int(quiz_current_line)]]
            quiz_current_line = int(quiz_current_line) + int(1)
            quiz_question_option = int(quiz_question_option) + int(1)
        quiz_question_answer = quiz_info[int(quiz_current_line)]
        quiz_current_line = int(quiz_current_line) + int(1)
        option, index = pick(options, title, indicator='[>]', default_index=0)    #problem
        if option == quiz_question_answer:
            quiz_score = quiz_score + int(1)
```

**I'm expecting to get a list of options that matches the options of the current question of from file already mentioned.**

Comment: Side note: if something is already an int, there is not need to call `int()` with it. That function can be used to convert things that are not ints to int - if possible. Examples: `int("22")`, `int(1.2)`, etc.

Comment: @001 I am aware, just chose to be safe in case I did an oopsie and made more errors on accident. I've only done that in that block of code though :)

Comment: Looks like the pick lib expects a string as argument #2 but you are passing a tuple. You can use `+` to concatenate strings. A comma creates a tuple.

Comment: In regards to all the `int()` calls, it clutters up the code and makes it more difficult to read. [Is code read more often than it's written?](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/a/48564). Just FYI.

Comment: @001 I'm adding to the list using 'options += [quiz_info[quiz_current_line]]', how does this use commas to create the tuple?

Comment: You have this line `title = '-----------\n QUIZZABLE \n-----------\n   Quiz    \n-----------\n\nQuiz:', quiz_title` The comma makes this a tuple.  I think you meant to use `+` instead of `,`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As commented by John Gordon: it was in fact the title that was causing the problem, and thank you.

> You have this line `title = '-----------\n QUIZZABLE \n-----------\n   Quiz    \n-----------\n\nQuiz:', quiz_title` The comma makes this a
> tuple. I think you meant to use `+` instead of `,`.